# mean curvature of a nonlinear parabolic PDE

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I want to compute the mean curvature of a reaction diffusion equations of the form
$$
u_t=u_{xx}-u^2
$$

Any suggestions is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by the mean curvature of a PDE?